# Can I use the IMEI to identify mobiles for my android app

Tags: android, ios, mobile

As IMEI means '**International Mobile Station Equipment Identity**'

Is it a good solution to identify a mobile phone for an Android/iOS app ?

Answer (score -1):

As per apple app store regulations you can no longer use the IMEI to identify mobile phones, and any applications that use this technique will be rejected.

This also applies on the MAC address.